# Adding polymer elements to DOM using jquery

Tags: jquery, polymer

I am trying to dynamically add polymer elements to a page, but am having trouble having accessing the elements.

Specifically, I am trying to add additional [swipeable cards](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/swipeable-card) to a page (later based on information I will pass on when the page is rendered).

```
    <core-scaffold id="scaffold">


        <!--Elements in scaffold window-->
        <div id="cards" layout vertical center-center fit>
                <swipeable-card>Swipe Me!</swipeable-card>
                <swipeable-card>Swipe Me!</swipeable-card>
        </div>  
</core-scaffold>


<div id="add_button">
<paper-fab icon="add"></paper-fab>
</div>
```

I am able to access the `add_button` div, but since the `cards` div is inside a polymer element, I am unable to access it. I have tried to access [it as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764727/3691484) but have not had any luck. Is dynamically adding Polymer elements something that is possible with Jquery? My end result would involve passing an array of objects, and creating a card for each object, listing a few properties.